# Android ListAdapter displays correct but then gives NullPointer. Why?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I'm trying to build a simple listadapter in my Android app. I got it to display the list of items correctly, but strangely, after the list displays, I get a Nullpointer and the app crashes. Seeing that the adapter is rather simple, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here.

Below my adapter. The Nullpointer occurs in the getView method at the line saying `holder.points.setText("123");`

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Question> data = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private Context context;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView points;
        TextView title;
    }

    public void setList(List<Question> questionList) {
        this.data = questionList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Question question = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_question, null);
            holder.points = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_points);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_title);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.points.setText("123");
        holder.title.setText(question.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Question getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: does R.id.text_question_points belong to list_item_question?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing `convertView.setTag(holder)` anywhere.

As a result when you do

```
 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
```

`holder` will be null and it will give you a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

here

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_question, null);
        holder.points = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_points);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);//this is it
    }
```

That is why, the second time we use this convertView, and convertView != null. `holder` is null in this line `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`.

**Edit**
That said, although I am no debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Question> data = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private Context context;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView points;
        TextView title;
    }

    public void setList(List<Question> questionList) {
        this.data = questionList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Question question = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_question, null);
            holder.points = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_points);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_question_title);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.points.setText("123");
        holder.title.setText(question.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Question getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function

```
 setList(List<Question> questionList)
```

there for data list contains no values. That's why it shows null pointer exception.

Correct it,and check....